# How to Analyze DAG Time Complexity?

Tags: python, algorithm

I am learning about topological sort, and graphs in general. I implemented a version below using DFS but I am having trouble understanding why the wikipedia page says this is O(|V|+|E|) and analyzing its time complexity, and the difference between |V|+|E| and n^2 in general.

Firstly, I have two for loops, logic says that it would be (n^2) but also isnt it true that in any DAG(or Tree), there is n-1 edges, and n vertexes? How is this any different from n^2 if we can remove the "-1" for non significant value?

```
graph = {
 1:[4, 5, 7],
 2:[3,5,6],
 3:[4],
 4:[5],
 5:[6,7],
 6:[7],
 7:[]
}



from collections import defaultdict

def topological_sort(graph):
    ordered, marked = [], defaultdict(int)

    while len(ordered) < len(graph):
        for vertex in graph:
           if marked[vertex]==0:
                visit(graph, vertex, ordered, marked)

return ordered

def visit(graph, n, ordered, marked):
    if marked[n] == 1:
        raise 'Not a DAG'

    marked[n] = 1

    for neighbor in graph.get(n):
        if marked[neighbor]!=2:
            visit(graph, neighbor, ordered, marked)

    marked[n] = 2

    ordered.insert(0, n)


def main():
print(topological_sort(graph))

main()
```

Comment: For anyone else not up on their initialisms: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph

Comment: It's `O(|V| + |E|)` because each node gets visited once and each edge gets visited once.  If a node were to get visited twice, it would not be a DAG, because there would be a cycle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper implementation works in `O(|V| + |E|)` time because it goes through every edge and every vertex at most once. It's the same thing as `O(|V|^2)` for a complete (or almost complete graph). However, it's much better when the graph is sparse.

You implementation is `O(|V|^2)`, not `O(|V| + |E|)`. These two nested loops:

```
while len(ordered) < len(graph):
    for vertex in graph:
         if marked[vertex]==0:
               visit(graph, vertex, ordered, marked)
```

do `1 + 2 ... + |V| = O(|V|^2)` iterations in the worst case (for instance, for an empty graph). You can easily fix by getting rid of the outer loop (it's that simple: just remove the while loop. You don't need it).

Comment: Oh ok, I initially converted the wikipedia psuedocode to code, and it has a while loop in it.

Comment: @driftdrift The wikipedia code is slightly different. They remove the vertex before going to. No vertex is considered twice, so their time complexity is `O(V + E)`. It looks like a small detail, but it turns out to be important.